# Error installing Contact Form 7 

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

What is the procedure to use this plug-in correctly? I have made a form using contact form 7, but when I test the form it fails to send an email with an error message "Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact administrator by other way." How can I fix this issue?

Comment: there is no procedure , you install both plugins and activate. try sending the form before you activate Contact Form 7 to Database first

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to setup smtp for it to work. Your host probably has disabled the php mail function try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

I have found when using CF7 that when I get this error it is due to incorrect MX record setups, or simply your web host does not allow email relaying.

Try setting the 'From' field on the CF7 form to wordpress@yourdomain.com this seems to work 99% of the time.